# model method trigger boolean to true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, triggers, model

How can I trigger method `accomplished_challenge` upon `days_left_challenged == 0`?

### challege.rb

```
  before_save :days_left_challenged_sets_deadline

  # makes ongoing_challenge become past (before_save) THIS WORKS
  def days_left_challenged_sets_deadline
    if self.date_started != nil 
      if days_left_challenged <= 0
        self.accomplished = true
        self.deadline = self.date_started
      end
    end
  end

  # makes ongoing_challenge become past (whenever gem) THIS DOESN'T
  def self.accomplished_challenge
    self.all.each do |challenge|
      if challenge.days_left_challenged <= 0
        challenge.accomplished = true
        challenge.deadline = self.date_started
      end
    end
  end

 # Counts down how many days left in days_challenged using committed
 def days_left_challenged
   self.days_challenged - ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
     committed_wdays.include? date.wday
   end + self.missed_days
 end
```

### Challenge.last

```
 id: 1,
 action: "Run",
 committed: ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", ""],
 date_started: Sat, 06 Feb 2016 00:00:00 EST -05:00,
 deadline: nil,
 accomplished: nil,
 days_challenged: 10,
 missed_days: 0,
```

I can't trigger it with a callback or validation I don't think since `days_left_challenged` can turn to `0` at any point in the life of a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a gem like [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to setup a cron job to run every day or so and do that checking for all Challenges. It would be something like:

```
every 1.day, :at => '0:01 am' do
  runner "Challenge.accomplished_challenge"
end
```

And your `accomplished_challenge` must be a class method that checks all (or the one you choose using a filter) Challenges:

```
def self.accomplished_challenge
  self.all.each do |challenge|
    if challenge.days_left_challenged == 0
      challenge.update_attributes(deadline: self.date_started, accomplished: true)         
    end
  end
end
```

---- EDIT to work on Heroku ----

Create a task on `/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake`:

```
# /lib/tasks/scheduler.rake

desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :check_accomplished_challenges => :environment do
  puts "Checking accomplished challenges..."
  Challenge.accomplished_challenge
  puts "done."
end
```

Go to your heroku app Resources page and add 'Heroku Scheduler'. Open the scheduler and add the task:

```
rake check_accomplished_challenges
```

Set it to run every day.
More details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For some reason though it didn't work. I bundle install `gem 'whenever', :require => false`. Then `wheneverize .` Then I added your top code to `schedule.rb` and your bottom code to `challenge.rb`. I made a challenge yesterday which would hit `challenge.days_left_challenged == 0` today and then checked today to see if it updated `accomplished = true` and `challenge.deadline = self.date_started` but it didn't :/ Thanks for trying.

Comment: Was your server running at 0:01 am?

Comment: I did it in production with heroku

Comment: It won't work on heroku. I will update my answer in order for it to work.

Comment: Hey Akz. I've been trying these past two days to make and see if your code works, but I can't get it to. I made the frequency hourly for testing. It last ran `Mar 11 18:21 UTC`  according to Heroku Scheduler. Then when I take a look at the `challenge` that has `challenge.days_left_challenged <= 0` `accomplished` & `date_started` remains `nil`

Comment: Hey updated question with code from my current model. I'm able to make a version of your code work with `before_save` if a user decides to create a challenge he already accomplished. But making it work with `whenever` is the issue.

Comment: The method `accomplished_challenge` isn't saving the changes we make. That's why it works on a `before_save`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I believe it will be easier to test using `rails console`.

Comment: I'll update you when heroku scheduler last run updates in a hour and check with `heroku run rails c` to see if `challenge` updates :]

Comment: `whenever` ran again, but it didn't update `deadline` or `accomplished`. Maybe there is a way to write it into the rake.scheduler? I'm testing now `desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :check_accomplished_challenges => :environment do
  puts "Checking accomplished challenges..."
  if Challenge.days_left_challenged <= 0
    Challenge.update_all(deadline: self.date_started, accomplished: true)         
  end
  puts "done."
end`